# Модуль для joomla - фотогалерея

Tags: joomla

Нужен модуль для джумлы, чтобы для отдельного пользователя показывалась отдельная фотогалерея.

Comment: @vkovalchuk88, ХэшКод это не фриланс биржа. Перефразируйте ваш вопрос, уточните, что сделали сами, что не получилось.

Comment: не нашел тогда модуль, не получилось:) за меня не надо ничего делать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JW Simple Image Gallery подошел, тот, который необходим для K2.

Answer (score 0):

Отличное расширение. Уже поставил себе версию 3.0.7 + русский язык. Все это брал  [здесь](http://cmsheaven.org/extensions/joomla/components/).